# Sharepoint Masterpage different when logged in as a Visitor?

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, master-pages, sharepoint-designer

using sharepoint 2007, I have created a new master page for my company and published all the necessary files i worked with. However, this works fine when I am logged on and if I log on using a user that is a visitor, it reflects differently. I have been to the Master Page settings and modified the different settings but no luck. Please could someone assist me with what could possibly cause this?

May you also please provide a source I can use to style web parts styles. I would like to apply borders for webparts in the main content zone and those on the right zone/panel, apply a different container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site visitors cannot see items in "Draft", including the masterpage. Make sure it is published and approved.

The easiest way to be able to style the right zone separate from the main zone would be the addition of classed div around the relevant section of the page layout.

Comment: I figured out why the images where not included. I navigated to the folder where the images are stored and noticed that there were not included in the folder, however, these appeared in the sharepoint portal. I had added these by dragging them via Sharepoint Designer and think there were not published even though I had checked them in  against a major version. I then deleted these from the sharepoint portal and added them again and published against a major version in the sharepoint portal and it now works. Thank you for the help.